# Django models Manager isn't accessible via model instances

Tags: django, django-models

I get this error 'Manager isn't accessible via Stage instances'. I have spent few good hours trying to work it out but I have got no clue what I am doing wrong.

models.py

```
class StageManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(StageManager, self).get_queryset().filter(stage=self.id, stage__zone=self.zone).aggregate(Sum('substage_value'))


class Stage(models.Model):
    tablerow_stage = models.ForeignKey(TRStage)
    stage_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager
    subs_objects = StageManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s.%s.%s' % (self.zone.project,
                             self.tablerow_stage.stage_num,
                             self.zone.zone_num)
```

line of code from template:

```
<td style="width:40px" align="center">{{ stage.subs_objects }}</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not allow you to do `stage.objects`, only `Stage.objects` (only via class, not instance of the class). Your custom queryset follows the same rule. But thing is, even if this was allowed, you queryset would not work - you are referencing fields such as `id` and `zone` that only exist in model instances, not managers.

Now I'm not entirely sure what you are actually trying to achieve, but here's a method you can stick in the `Stage` class instead of having that queryset.

```
def substage_sum(self):
    return self.__class__.objects.filter(
        stage=self.id, 
        stage__zone=self.zone
    ).aggregate(
        sum=Sum('substage_value')
    ).values_list('sum', flat=True).first()
```

This would return a single value that represents the sum, assuming that's what you want.

Comment: how can I access this substage_class from templates so I can access substage_sum value for each Stage object ?

Comment: The method I described is to be put in your model, and it will be accessible from templates like everything else on the model (`{{ stage.substage_sum }}`). You may need to update it if I didn't guess what you were trying to achieve correctly.

Comment: thanks for your comments however i have tried it before submitting my comments. I get this error 'Cannot resolve keyword 'stage' into field. Choices are: id, slug, stage_value, substage, tablerow_stage, tablerow_stage_id, zone, zone_id' when I try access substage_sum

Comment: I have class Stage and class SubStage. Substage is related to Stage. So, I am trying to filter SubStage objects by Stage. So, your example does not fully work for me.

Comment: I have done this:     def substage_sum(self):
        return SubStage.objects.filter(stage=self.id,stage__zone=self.zone).aggregate(sum=Sum('substage_value')) and it works.